# Immediate public reaction of being teleported to a new galaxy

Tags: society, wormholes, behaviour

The basis of this sci-fi worldbuilding story/project is this: a well-meaning attempt to create artificial wormholes succeeds, but creates a wormhole so huge that it consumes Earth, the now-colonised Mars, Venus and mercury, the sun and transports them to a far-flung galaxy, where humans then contact aliens, explore, etc.

But going back to the initial point immediately after the wormhole event, what would be the reaction of the public when they saw the stars had changed and the authorities told them what had happened?

Comment: "Colonized" can imply a very large range of space capability and familiarity, from "We have some orbiting outposts where people won't immediately die" to "We terraformed the worlds and  they're independent nations with populations in the billions."  Also would be helpful to know who did the wormhole experiment, how public it was, and why.

Comment: You have not told us what the population of each of the planets is, typical level of education, prevalent religious beliefs (if any), level of media control by the government or anything else that might let a considered answer be written.  We also don't know if anyone/anything was "left behind" eg outer solar system expeditions. However, it is unanswerable because "the public" consists of lots of individuals who will react in different ways.  How would you say that "the public" has reacted to the news of ongoing climate change?  Or the invasion of Ukraine?  VTC.

Comment: VTC Too Story-Based. Also VTC:Not About Worldbuilding, per the [help/on-topic], we do not accept questions about the choices (reactions) of people or organizations.

Comment: @JBH Reactions are not always choices, but I agree that it is heavily reliant on which spark ignites the main reaction here, how this journalist *chose* to showcase the case. It is unlikely to trigger a predictable reaction on the whole society every time. All this is heavily worsened by the lack of the initial conditions : What kind of society is this? How/when wormhole projects are seen? What part of the population would you like to know about (the whole will almost always see opposite reactions)?

Comment: @JBH  we can't ask about CNN or the CIA on this stack, which would be off topic indeed. But the opener has not mentioned any specific real-world people or organizations,  The question is about *"reaction of the public"*. The answer can be a global description. We do agree this is story based, but the actor in that rule would be a collective: "the public", that is general population. Ignoring the book rule (!!) I've upvoted this and attempted to put an answer. I find it a very interesting scenario to think about.

Comment: @Tortliena It's still too story based. It also violates the book rule because my little sister will react differently than you or I or the OP. It violates the rule of all answers being of equal value because nobody on this Stack is godlike and can judge how any group of people will react to anything. Pick your poison. We've always closed questions like this because the answer depends too heavily on [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).

Comment: @Goodies [Real Life cannot be an overriding limitation on any question unless specifically requested](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8143/40609). Worse, per the [help/on-topic], we deal in helping people develop *imaginary worlds.* Whether or not Real Life is involved is utterly irrelevant. In fact, if anything, you've made my point. How can anyone on this stack determine how a *fictional* population will react?

Comment: Perhaps all you people who don't want rules applied to this Stack should get off your lazy behinds, head over to Meta, and join the discussion about permitting or prohibiting brainstorming questions.

Comment: @JBH That's just not how psychology and sociology works :). Most of my popular science references in this regard are French, but this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZueeA9b1xY)'s subtitled in English and this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sgracmBZ98) can be auto-translated. Should give you a better view of why and how soft sciences work, and why you're not that "free" to choose. Point is, asking about the "likelyhood" of something to happen is on-topic, as stated in the link provided by the story-based closure reason. Minus other close reasons, of course :).

Comment: (P.S. @JBH : Brainstorm is irrelevant here. We're talking about whether it's story-based or not. Don't make the confusion when you explicitly make the difference in your [meta-post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10012/a-proposal-to-end-the-love-hate-relationship-with-brainstorming-aka-list-questi) :p).

Comment: @Tortliena We're talking about ignoring rules. I don't care which poison you pick. And my point about my meta post is that we have a growing group of people who want to ignore the rules as they see fit (including you) without any discussion in Meta (proving a point Sphennings made). Answer this question quickly. It's about to get closed.

Comment: @JBH Your point of view, not mine and not what your topic says (ref. : section "Why am I Asking for This Vote?") :). I won't answer it anyway, as I won't answer any question I voted to close as recommended by the [help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). But you're free to engage a chat discussion with me, ti's not the first time I offered this opportunity...

Answer (score 1):

## Indifference

The news itself was spectacular, in the view of journalists, scientists and WB-members.

But nothing actually *changed* on the planet surface, 95% of folks didn't notice.

The notion of sun, planets and Earth moving instantly is beyond grasp.

Life will proceed, after two weeks Earth News will report about stuff that happens on the planet.

Some astronomers will publish interesting books about worm holes and new skies.

Other astronomers will have lost their research subjects, and as a result, their job.

Comment: Amateur astronomers: outrage at losing all their usual targets, excitement at having new ones. People in the cities: wouldn't notice if you didn't tell them. People in rural areas: "Huh. Neat. *sips beer*"

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Disbelief

How many people really know the stars, these days? GPS still works, and that is how we navigate. So you have government spokespersons, reputable media, etc. telling people that Earth and Sun have moved. Quite a lot of people will consider it all a big joke.

### 2. Apocalyptic Scenarios and Panic

What you describe **should** have no immediate impact on life on Earth. But try telling that the people. Panic buying, disruption of supply chains, a surge in doomsday cults.

### 3. Conspiracy Theories

There are people who refuse to believe in climate change, Covid, or the Moon landings. They will start spinning theories about what *really* happened and who orchestrated it for what nefarious purpose. There is already part of the population who are predisposed to see sinister motives in *anything* that what they call mainstream media agree on.

These might stoke item 2. Panic much longer than it would ordinarily last. People buy toilet paper and pasta, toilet paper and pasta run short, people buy more of it because it runs short, it runs even shorter, etc.

### 4. Fitting it into our Worldview

Christianity mostly managed to fit Copernicus and Darwin into their daily life, but the discoveries are still making waves. So spiritual leaders will try to reconcile it with doctrine and scripture, while scientific leaders will try to overhaul their theories.